# Linux writing a txt with a few variables ordered in columns

Tags: linux, variables, series

I want to write a txt document with multiple lines organized by 3 columns A, B and C separated by a space

where A is always the same name.
B is a sequence of values, i.e. seq 1 100
C are the cycling of 5 names, i.e. "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" and then starting again at "a"

for example:

nameA 1 a

nameA 2 b

nameA 3 c

nameA 4 d

nameA 5 e

nameA 6 a

...

I tried playing with the seq command and making a variable of it, but then don't know how to pool together these 3 variables into one document, or make one variable of the 3 factors (A B C) altogether.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways this can be achieved, I'll start with the one I think is most elegant;

```
$ colA="nameA"
$ colC=({a..e})
$ for colB in $(seq 100); do
>     echo "$colA $colB ${colC[($colB-1) % ${#colC[@]}]}" >> document.txt
> done
```

Explanation;
`colC` is created as an array which can be accessed by an index. The length of the array can be accessed using the pound sign (`#`), and all items can be accessed by using the at (`@`) as index. Note that `seq` will start at 1 by default, but array indices start at 0, so the range should be 0 to 4.

```
$ colC=({a..e})
$ echo "All items: ${colC[@]}, length: ${#colC[@]}"
All items: a b c d e, length: 5
$ for index in $(seq 0 4); do
>     echo "index: $index, value: ${colC[$index]}"
> done
index: 0, value: a
index: 1, value: b
index: 2, value: c
index: 3, value: d
index: 4, value: e
```

By accessing the division remainder between the current loop and the length of the array (modulo operator `%`), the corresponding item will be printed accordingly. The first line in the example is `nameA 1 a`, so the current index has to be increased by one (if starting from 0), or reduced by 1 when accessing the array items, as in the example above. Otherwise, the result will start with either `nameA 0 a`, or `nameA 1 b`, accordingly. Replace `document.txt` with your target file name.

---

Another method can be to artificially increase the value of `colB`, while instructing `seq` to skip 5 items. This method may be simpler, but it requires the total lines to be a factor of 5 (it does not handle, for example, 102 rows), so I don't recommend this, just posting this to show how:

```
$ colA="nameA"
$ for colB in $(seq 1 5 100); do
>     for colC in {a..e}; do
>         echo "$colA $colB $colC" >> document.txt
>         colB=$((colB+1))
>     done
> done
```